# Recover data in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, data-recovery

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 right now on my laptop. I have a **laptop hard drive** that I want to recover data from it. I tried every possible method to get my lost data back but none was successful as I thought. I know I can get at least few amount of them but I don't know when I tried to recover data from it, it only shows me some "Windows 7" system files and that's it.

I'm glad if you can let me know these things,

- What is the best way to recover data in Linux?
- How many percentage of data will I able to recover?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org/Download) - it is a special purpose distro created for problems like yours.

You will need to burn it on a CD or make a bootable USB. The built-in Startup Disk Creator application can be used to make a bootable SystemRescueCd USB.

Then you need a second computer/laptop. Remove its hard disk, install the disk you want to recover data from and boot SystemRescueCd

The Windows7 system files are probably on the system recovery partition. Look for other partitions on the same drive, your data is most likely on the last 1-2 partitions.

And bear in mind that if the disk has been physically damaged you may not be able to recover your data. That is why people invented backups.